# How to get value from soap message?

Tags: java, xml, soap

I want to ask if there are any ways to retrieve data from soap request? I know this question may be asked frequently. However I cannot find a great answer that suit my question.
Here is my request:

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<ns1:getFruit soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <aGetFruitRequest href="#id0"/>
</ns1:getFruit>
<multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:GetFruitRequest">
    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">apple</name>
    <type xsi:type="xsd:string">fruit</type>
</multiRef>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I want to get the value 'apple' and 'fruit' that is in the tag 'name' and 'type'. Is there any way to do that in java?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) or but if all if you want is to extract those values you can use [JXPath](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/) instead to parser the response yourself.